# How do I use a hook to modify CiviCRM payment processor details in Webform?

Tags: webforms, 9, civicrm

I am trying to use `hook_form_alter()` to change the details of the CiviCRM Payment Processor for specific users (to change from live mode to test mode).

On Drupal 7 it's in `$form['submitted']` when *Page 2* is rendered.  Many items are already there on *Page 1*, but this is not.

Are these somewhere else, or do I have to use a different mechanism, in Drupal 9?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an extension. See here:

https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/

But that's for CiviCRM hooks. Drupal hooks indeed still work in a .module file. Docs are here:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/9

To see all of the various parts, you can use

```
$formValues = $form_state->getUserInput();
print_r($formValues);die;
```

once, in order to see all the values. You can then use

```
$form_state->setValue();
```

to set a value.

Comment: As above, I used a hook successfully but can't find the right thing to edit on D8/9